# Banner Ad is not getting displayed in App after Publishing in Playstore

Tags: android, kivy, admob, buildozer, pyjnius

I have developed android app using Kivy and kivmob, I recently added a banner ad and rolled out into production.

But after updating the app in Google Play Store, My app doesn't show any ads.

I have tested in two to three test devices

**Please find the code below**

```
from kivmob import KivMob
...
class Myapp(app):
...
    def build(self):
       self.ads = KivMob("ca-app-pub-99450064956xxxxx~xxxxxxxx")
       self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-99450064956xxxxx/xxxxxxxx", top_pos=False)
       self.ads.request_banner()
       self.ads.show_banner()
```

**Buildozer Spec:**

```
  requirements = kivy, android, jnius, kivmob
  ...
  android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
  android.api = 29
  android.minapi = 21
  android.sdk = 24
  android.ndk = 19b
  android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
  p4a.branch = master
  android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-99450064956xxxxx~xxxxxxxx
```

Please find an error in the above code.

Kindly suggest some other options in kivy to display the ad in live.

Comment: Actually code wise everything is correct. And in buildozer.spec also there are no errors. Did you try it in the in your phone, during development. Like do you have any logs

Comment: Thanks Sivaram, No error found. My actual code is working fine. Only ads are not displaying. Do I need to wait for some days for the ads to be displayed

Comment: to test, use this banner id - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111. If that is working then you have to wait or there is some issue with your admob account

Comment: Thanks Sivaram, I got an update from admob. They confirmed that after admob activation, Ads will be displayed. I have opened my account today. So it's not yet activated. Once again thank you Sivaram for your valuable time and prompt response

Comment: great. glad to know that admob responded to you